# Date in XLSX file not parsing correctly in SheetJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sheetjs

I am trying to read a XLSX file using sheetjs node-module with a column having dates. After parsing I got data in incorrect format

File data is : 2/17/2020

But after xlsx read it gives me 2/17/20. It is changing the year format. My requirement is to get the data as it is.

Sample Code:

```
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('a.xlsx', {
  sheetRows: 10
});
    
var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'], {
  header: 1,
  defval: '',
  blankrows: true,
  raw: false
});
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a solution presented [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/718) using streams but can equally work with `readFile`. The problem that was at play in the issue is that the value for the `dateNF` option in [`sheet_to_json`](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#json) needs some escape characters.

E.g.:

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const filename = './Book4.xlsx';

const readOpts = { // <--- need these settings in readFile options
  cellText:false, 
  cellDates:true
};

const jsonOpts = {
  header: 1,
  defval: '',
  blankrows: true,
  raw: false,
  dateNF: 'd"/"m"/"yyyy' // <--- need dateNF in sheet_to_json options (note the escape chars)
}

const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filename, readOpts);
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'];
const json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, jsonOpts);

console.log(json);
```

For this input:

[image]

Will output:

```
[
  [ 'v1', 'v2', 'today', 'formatted' ],
  [ '1', 'a', '14/8/2021', '14/8/2021' ]
]
```

Without the `dateNF: 'd"/"m","/yyyy'` you get same problem as you describe in the question:

```
[
  [ 'v1', 'v2', 'today', 'formatted' ],
  [ '1', 'a', '8/14/21', '8/14/21' ]
]
```

The two potential unwanted side effects are:

1. use of the `cellText` and `cellDates` options in `readFile`
2. note my custom format of `yyyy^mmm^dd` in the input - the `dateNF` setting overrides any custom setting

Comment: But if I define format the date column which is in another format will be also changed. I want to read it as string so that whatever value is there it should print as it is

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I fixed it by setting raw option to true.

```
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('a.xlsx', {
  sheetRows: 10
  raw: true
});
```

This is what it says in the documentation:

> raw - If true, plain text parsing will not parse value **